# VBA: Sorting quarterly data

Tags: excel, vba

I am filtering some data to only include quarterly data for month 01, 4, 7 and 10. When I use the following code it doesn't delete the correct rows.
The format in column one that is being searched is yyyy.mm , e.g. `1871.01` or `1871.1` 
In my case it deletes e.g. `1871.01` which is a mistake.

```
    Sub sortcape()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Set sht = Sheets(2)
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sht.Cells(2, 4) = LastRow

For i = LastRow To 9 Step -1
If InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".01") <> 5 And InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".04") <> 5 And InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".07") <> 5 And _
InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".1") <> 5 Then
sht.Rows(i).Delete
End If
Next i

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sht.Cells(2, 5) = LastRow

For i = LastRow To 9 Step -1
If InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".11") = 5 Or InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".12") = 5 Then
sht.Rows(i).Delete
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

**EDIT: Updated with working code, thanks to the contributors.**

Comment: Loop backwards when deleting or gather all qualifying rows with union and delete the union range in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common logic fallacy. If one of the conditions is false, at least one of the other conditions is going to be true.

Change all of the Or operators to And. This will delete the row when none of the conditions are true.

```
If InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".01") <> 5 And InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".04") <> 5 And _
   InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".07") <> 5 And InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".1") <> 5 Then
```

As mentioned in the comments, deleting rows should always be performed from bottom to top.

```
For i = LastRow to 9 step -1
```

Comment: Thank you. Brain fart on my part, this works. Cheers. Updating my code to reflect what worked for me.